# How to change layout of each items in preferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I'm a beginner of Android development and wanna design an app which allows users change the font-size of each item in preferenceScreen. I've prepared three different layout resources, **small**, **medium** and **large**, and added attribute "`layout`" to each item like "`EditPreference`" "`CheckBoxPreference`" "`ListPreference`".

I want to use a **LisPreference** which in charge of adjusting font_size to change every item's layout resource.

Here's code of Preference.XML :

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="@string/preference_pers_info"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_userInfo">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/preference_user_name"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_userName"
        android:summary="@string/pref_sum_userName"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_deVel_userName"
        android:layout="@layout/menu_big_font_size"/>
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/font_size"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_gridDensity"
        android:summary="@string/pref_sum_gridDensity"
        android:defaultValue="10"
        android:layout="@layout/menu_big_font_size"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

[Here's the three layout XML i wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRwFF.png)

[intend to change through this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHIsO.jpg)

So I dont know how to switch different predefined layout resource by using preference itself. Hoping for a good lesson! Thx in advance!!!

Comment: why don't you try replacing the fragment with each type of selection and each fragment will refer to your desired xml layout.

Comment: Thats a good idea, I'll have a try. thank you !